# Using .jar files in the main function

Tags: java

Once I import .jar file to the main function. I have done everything correctly : (Right
clickproject-­‐>Properties-­‐>JavaBuildPath-­‐>Libraries-­‐>AddJARs).

Now if I want to start using methods and variables from a class that's in the .jar file.

In the main function, do I just declare an object of the class type and start using methods from the class?

I tried that and it keeps giving me the `error: "Syntax error on token ";", @ expected"`

```
package abcd;

import util.Car;

public class Showroom {

   Car firstCar = new Car("BMW"); //overloaded constructor 

   Car secondCar = new Car(); //default constructor is empty 

   secondCar.setName("Lexus"); //setName is a method in the Car class but I get the above error for using this. 

}
```

I know it has a very easy solution but can you please explain what and why?

Comment: `Using .jar files in the main function` ... in which main "function"? There is none. Probably you should create one, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

In java you can write logics only in some method or blocks.

so something like this

```
public void someMethod(Car secondCar){
secondCar.setName("Lexus");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to write statements in executable block (constructor, method, initializer block)

```
secondCar.setName("Lexus");
```